# Is the following expression positive or negative?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is the following inequality a positive or negative quantity?

$$ F= 2 \sqrt 2 \ |x| \ \text{Re}(x) - |x|^2$$

I am not sure how one can simplify it further if $\text{Re}(x)$ was equal to $|x| $ than we know that

$$ 2 \sqrt 2 \ |x|^2 - |x|^2 >0$$ but in general I don't know if it positive or not.

If this cannot be determined, is there any relationship between 
$$|x| \ \text{and} \ \text{Re}(x)$$

i.e which one is bigger?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither.

Set $x=1$ to get $2\sqrt2\cdot1\cdot1-1^2=2\sqrt2-1>0$.
Set $x=i$ to get $2\sqrt2\cdot1\cdot0-1^2=-1<0.$

About your relationship, $|x|=|a+bi|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\ge\sqrt{a^2}=|a|=|\text{Re}\,x|\ge\text{Re}\,x$.

Answer (score 1):

It can be both :

Take for example, $x = 1$ and $x = -1$

Answer (score 0):

$Re(x)$ can be negative itself and then $F$ is negative. If like in your example $Re(x) = |x|$ then F is positive. So $F$ does not have the same sign for every complex $x$.

Because $|x| = \sqrt(Re^2(x) + Im^2(x)) >= \sqrt(Re^2(x)) = |Re(x)| $. So there is relation
$ |x| >= |Re(x)|$